# Can users connecting to my server download mods directly from me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I set up my own minecraft-Forge 1.10.2 server with a few mods on it.

My question is now: Can I achieve, that connecting Clients automatically download missing mods so they can play on my server without hours of seeking for the mods, or downloading the modpack?

I want to ask the user like "Do you want to download the missing mods?"

If that is possible, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible and I seriously do hope so, since it's a major security risk to download and install something without the user's direct permission.

Comment: i dont want to do it THAT automatically xD ofc its a sec-risk... i want something like "u dont have da mods, u need to DL, do u want?" thing

Comment: That wasn't specific for your case. But if you can do it, everyone can - and not everyone has good intentions by doing this.

Comment: srry, ill add id to my question, ofcourse i do not want to support "bad-intentios"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pack and publish it on the Curse launcher and tell them the code.

The launcher then will download and maintain the mods required to connect to your server for them.